# If it is given which intervals are spacelike, can be determined which intervals are lightlike?

Tags: general-relativity, mathematical-physics

Provided that the notion of "$\mbox{spacelike}$"-ness (of an interval) is symmetric: $$\text{spacelike}( \, x - y \, ) \Longleftrightarrow \text{spacelike}( \, y - x \, ),$$
then for any set $X$ (of sufficiently many elements) the set $X^2$ (of all pairs, regardless of order, of not necessarily distinct elements of $X$) may be partitioned into three disjoint and generally non-empty subsets

- of pairs containing the same element twice: $I_X := \{ x \in X: (x x) \}$,
- of pairs of distinct elements whose interval is (called) "$\text{spacelike}$": $S_X := \{ x \in X \, \& \, y \in X \, \& \, x \ne y \, \& \, \text{spacelike}( x - y ): (x y) \}$, and
- of all remaining pairs $K_X := X^2 \backslash (I_X \cup S_X)$.

Provided further that the notion of "$\mbox{lightlike}$"-ness (of an interval) is symmetric as well: $$\text{lightlike}( \, x - y \, ) \Longleftrightarrow \text{lightlike}( \, y - x \, ),$$
and given a suitable set $X$ (of sufficiently many elements) and a suitable set $S_X$ satisfying $X^2 \cap S_X = S_X$, 
how would the corresponding set $K_X$ be partitioned further into two disjoint and generally non-empty subsets

- of pairs of distinct elements whose interval is (called) "$\text{lightlike}$": $L_X := \{ x \in X \, \& \, y \in X \, \& \, x \ne y \, \& \, \text{lightlike}( x - y ): (x y) \}$, and
- of all remaining pairs $T_X := K_X \backslash L_X$
  ?

**Edit**

The wording of this question (apart from formatting issues) as it presently stands appears not adequate to the title. (Helpful responses to it have been received nevertheless, which I try to incorporate in going forward.)

In trying to improve the detailed wording, what would need to be considered first is (put roughly, for the time being, as I've come to consider it only recently):

(1) Whether and how the topological notion of "*boundary*" can be suitably generalized to the context of sets of pairs such as $X^2$ and $S_X$, and

(2) Whether, given a particular set $X$, the predicate "$spacelike()$" in the definition of set $S_X$ implies certain relations to a corresponding set $K_X$ which I did not state explicitly above; such as the absence of "*impossible figures*" wrt. membership of certain pairs in $S_X$ or $K_X$.

I plan to defer editing (apart from possible formatting) until these preliminary questions have been expressed more adequatly elsewhere.

Comment: Comment to the question(v1): The notation used for sets is in many places far from standard, see e.g. [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set-builder_notation) Wikipedia page.

Comment: In main body of your question you are effectively asking that if we are given two symmetric relations $S$ and $L$ on a set $X$, and if set of pairs of points which are $S$- related to each other are known, then is it possible to find set of pairs which are $L$-related to each other.

Comment: I wonder if the [tag:mathematical-physics] tag might be appropriate for this sort of question?

Comment: `@Qmechanic`: Based on the standard you recommend, how would you express for instance "set of pairs (regardless of order) of distinct elements of set $X$", please?

Comment: `@dushya`: Right -- keyword is "_effectively_". If in the question main body v(1) the predicates "$spacelike()$" and "$lightlike()$" were replaced by anonymous, distinct but otherwise unrelated predicates, say "$p()$" and "$q()$", then ... it's not an interesting question (and not adequate to the title).
So: what I've learned nevertheless from the incidental answer(s) is rather, that there **are** some specific relations between predicates "$spacelike()$" and "$lightlike()$", after all; I should ask about it more directly.
Now I wonder, whether to keep the title and to rephrase the main body?

Comment: `@David Zaslavsky`: I wonder how to proceed with this question: I like the title, as it may suggest something worthwhile to be asked and (possibly) answered; but I understand (now, thanks to already helpful answers or comments) that the question main body wording as it presently stands is inadequate wrt. the title (and the tagging may indeed need reconsidering, thanks for your suggestion). Unfortunately, I don't find this addressed in the [faq](http://physics.stackexchange.com/faq) ... Any advice, please?

Comment: `@David Zaslavsky`: I just learned the hard way that comments may only be edited for 5 minutes. Please insert:
[...] I understand (now, thanks to already helpful answers or comments) that the question main body wording as it presently stands is inadequate wrt. the title"_. Instead, there may first have to be other preparatory questions addressed_" (and [...]).

Comment: @user12262: If you would like, I could edit your question with standard notation. You can always roll back if you don't like the edits. Or improve further yourself.

Comment: `@Qmechanic`: Thanks, but I'd much rather like you to give an instructive example in a comment; for instance the example "set of pairs (regardless of order) of distinct elements of set $X$" I asked about already. I (hope that I) know sufficient "latex", but I'm struggling to express the example set "_in standard notation_". Also: please provide links on how to "_roll back_", or on how to find out about "_rolling back_" ...

Comment: For roll back, click on the "edited" button (as opposed to the "edit" button) to get to previous versions.

Comment: E.g. the diagonal set $I_X$ should read $I_X := \{(x,x) \mid x \in X \}$ rather than $I_X := \{ x \in X: (x x) \}$.

Comment: @Qmechanic Thanks; I find my way 'round a little better now. However: If I "_roll back_" to an older version, would all younger versions be erased? (That's the sort of things I'm worrying about; perhaps it's been Q/A-ed somewhere already ...). Now: Would the following rendition perhaps be more/sufficiently _standard_: <br>
`\{ (x y) : x \in X & y \in X & whatever( x y ) \}` ?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/5895/discussion-between-user12262-and-qmechanic)

Answer (score 2):

I think you can do this only if the set $X$ is a topological space.

For any point $x\in X$, construct the set $C(x)\subset X$ of points $y'\in X$ so that $(x,y')\in K_X$. For this construction to work, each $C(x)\cup\{x\}$ has to be a *closed set* in $X$. Denote by $\partial C(x)$ the boundary of $C(x)$.

Then,

$$L_X=\{(x,y)\in X\times X|y\in \partial C(x)\}$$

and

$$T_X=\{(x,y)\in X\times X|y\in \text{int } C(x)\}.$$

You can do an equivalent construction starting with $S_X$ instead of $K_X$.

---

The intuition behind this construction is that the lightcone at a point $x$ is the boundary of the points which are causally connected with $x$.

Comment: `@Cristi Stoica`: Very nice and efficient and intuitive! (Meanwhile I've been struggling through trying to cast the similar intuition into overlong logical formulas and constructions à la A.A.Robb ... &)
However: my question did not presume set $X$ to be given with a topology! (Sorry for having set the "general-relativity" tag then -- is there a more appropriate one? But I'm really glad you understood the sense of my question anyways.)
So: Is there perhaps a suitable topology being **induced** on set $X$, plainly by the given set $S_X$ ? (The sum of difficulties might come out the same.)

Comment: @user12262: If you don't have the topology, you need to have something else from which to extract the needed information. If we only know it is a set, it is not enough. However, surprisingly many situations allow us to construct a suitable topology. Even for so-called discrete theories this can be done (see e.g. http://philsci-archive.pitt.edu/4355/). If you can come with additional structure on your sets, for example if you can define the distance between $x$ and $y$, even if it is only when they are separated by a spacelike interval, then we can use it to solve the problem.

Comment: `@Cristi Stoica`: thanks for your insight and suggestions, FWIW to me in trying to phrase my question more adequatly (cmp. the recent "Edit" of my question). I wish I had a better grasp of (standard) mathematical terminology; to use (or avoid) what's available, and to claim what's not ...
Presuming distance (or at least quasi-distance) relations is of course not helpful to the experimentalist who rightly asks "How do we get that?". 
Also, if some "_additional structure_" itself is available, then it may not be mandatory to consider any topology which may (or may not) be thereby induced.