# Does EPR permit information to travel faster than light?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, special-relativity, faster-than-light, causality, epr-experiment

This question always throws me:

> Discuss if the EPR paradox violates special relativity?

The information of the state of one particle is instantaneously transmitted to the other particle, but does this count? Since this information is not usable and does not allow you to transmit a message - it is equivalent to just getting a random set of characters.

**Edit**

The answers to the [question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/15282/) states that basically what I have stated in my question. I am, however, more concerned whether it is counted as a violation of special relativity, I am aware that instantaneous communication does occur.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Quantum entanglement faster than speed of light?](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/15282/)

Comment: **NO**. This has been discussed in countless threads around here, e.g. http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/15282/, http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/34653/, http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/170744/ and others with special protocols, like http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/131025/

Comment: BTW: I don't think you mean travail as in "*to suffer the pangs of childbirth; be in labor*". So I edited it as "*travel*".

Comment: Depends on who you ask

Comment: @Jimmy360 No it doesn't! See [No-communication theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/No-communication_theorem) on Wikipedia.

Comment: The question in the edit is implicitly addressed in any of these questions and more explicitly expressed here: http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/61126/does-entanglement-not-immediately-contradict-the-theory-of-special-relativity **No**, entanglement does not violate special relativity, because special relativity only prohibits information transfer to be faster than light (think about the laser pointer on the moon). Since no instantaneous communication (i.e. information transfer) occurs, SR is not violated.

Comment: @gonenc Noncommunication theorem is not violated, even if there were superluminal signals. There are many other questions on the Stack Exchange that examined.